# Is an infinite collection of open sets still necessarily "open" when interpreted in the extended reals?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Say we have an collection of open sets such that each set is defined as $(-\frac{1}{n}, 1 + \frac{1}{n})$ for all $n$ in the set of positive integers. If we don't allow $\infty$ to exist, then every set in the collection is an open set. However, if we allow $n$ to extend to $\infty$, then does there exist a closed set among the collection of open sets that is defined as $[0,1]$?

I am asking this question specifically because I am writing a proof showing that the intersection of a finite collection of open sets is always open. However, it is my understanding that this property does not necessarily hold if the collection of open sets is not finite. While the current proof that I have written seems to hold for finite sets, I cannot figure out why the proof I've written doesn't necessarily hold for an infinite collection of open sets. In my mind, the set $(-\frac{1}{\infty}, 1 + \frac{1}{\infty})$ is a closed set, and if this is that case, my proof would (I think) hold for both finite and infinite collections of open sets. Obviously this is wrong, and something is off with my interpretation.

Should I scrap the whole notion of $\infty$ altogether and just work with real numbers? Is it really possible to consider a collection of infinite sets, though, without employing the notion of infinity?

Obviously I may have messed up somewhere else in the proof, but this is the specific element of it that I feel uncertain enough about such that it is preventing me from moving forward.

Edit: The definition of an open set that I'm working with is that an "open set" is a set such that for every point contained within the set, there is also an $\epsilon$-neighborhood of that point that is also contained within the set.

Comment: What is your definition of open set?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm new here, so I'm not sure whether I should respond to your comment or post an edit on my original post, so I'm doing both. The definition of an open set that I'm working with is that an "open set" is a set such that for every point contained within the set, there is also an ϵ-neighborhood of that point that is also contained within the set.

Comment: No problem. Either way to answer a comment is ok. When you make a comment, you can use "@username" to notify the person, so that is always a good idea.

Comment: So continuing, what do you mean by the set $A=(-\frac{1}{\infty},1+\frac{1}{\infty})$? What is your convention for $\frac{1}{\infty}$? I guess it should be zero, so is $A=(0,1)$? However, the problem is that an infinite intersection of open intervals is not an open interval in general (as opposed to the finite case): $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\left(-\frac{1}{n},1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$ is actually the closed interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: I understand that the intersection of the sets is closed, but my confusion is as to why we interpret the collection of the sets as open. My interpretation  is that there would be a set at $n = \infty$ such that $A = [0,1]$ rather than $A = (0,1)$, else it wouldn't make any sense to interpret the intersection of the sets as closed. Edit: Sorry-- it seems that hitting enter posts the comment? Are paragraph spacings allowed? To clarify, $\frac{1}{\infty} = 0$ and conventions being used are taken from [this text](http://ramanujan.math.trinity.edu/wtrench/texts/TRENCH_REAL_ANALYSIS.PDF).

Comment: I just commented but forgot to notify you, @LuizCordeiro. Thanks for the heads up on that.

Comment: You seem to be confusing a few concepts. A subset of $\mathbb{R}$ may be open or not. A collection of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ is not open, formally, but sometimes people speak of "an open collection" to mean "a collection of open sets". I am not sure what you mean when you say that "there would be a set at $n=\infty$[...]". The equality $\bigcap_n (-1/n,1+1/n)=[0,1]$ is proven using the archimedean principle, etc... so we are not really interpreting this intersection as a closed set. **It is** a closed set.

Comment: If you define $\frac{1}{\infty} = 0$ so that $A_{\infty} = (-\frac{1}{\infty}, 1+\frac{1}{\infty}) = [0,1]$, then your collection of sets contains a closed set.  However, this would be an unusual convention.  Usually, one would index these intervals by (as you say) positive integers.  That is, $A_n := (-\frac{1}{n}, 1+\frac{1}{n})$ is open for every natural number, and the collection $\{A_n : n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a collection of open sets.

Comment: Thanks @LuizCordeiro. Yes, I did mean "a collection of open sets." I'll be looking into the proof for the fact that the intersection of these sets is closed, which will likely be of some help, and in line with what both you and Xander Henderson have been saying, I will drop the notion of infinity when working on understanding this problem. Stackexchange seems to be telling me that this discussion is getting too long, so I'll leave it at that, but you've been very helpful. Much thanks!

Comment: If $\frac 1\infty = 0$, then $A_\infty = (0, 1 + 0) = (0,1)$, not $[0,1]$. If you think $\frac 1\infty$ is some number "just above $0$", then you are not in the extended reals, which only add $\pm\infty$ to the reals, not infinitesimals. If you are thinking of some number system that actually has infinitesimals, those add a whole continuum of infinitesimal numbers, not just $\pm \frac 1\infty$, so you would still not have the set $[0,1]$ in your collection.